# Gulp-wrap: how to use dynamic template files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-wrap

[`gulp-wrap`](https://github.com/adamayres/gulp-wrap) is an excellent tool allowing me to use template layout to populate HTML files:

```
gulp.src('/my/project/**/*.html')
    .pipe(wrap({ src: '/my/project/layout.tpl' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/my/webapp/'));
```

Now my situation is: for some HTML files (say, files with name containing 'special'), I need to use a different template layout `special.tpl`. How to incorporate into the workflow above? I have searched but got no result.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using [`gulp-switch`](https://github.com/popomore/gulp-switch):

```
function getLayout(file) {
    return file.path.indexOf('special') >= 0 ? 'special' : 'common';
}

return gulp.src(dpwFiles.pages)
    .pipe(gulpSwitch(getLayout, {
        common: wrap({src: 'layout.tpl' }),
        special: wrap({src: 'special.tpl' })
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/my/webapp'));
```

Comment: `gulp-switch` is [blacklisted](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json): `"gulp-switch": "duplicate of gulp-if",`.

Comment: Actually I have three kind of templates: `common`, `special` and `null`. `gulp-if` seems not adequate..